# How do I move an Exchange 2003 mailbox that has corrupt emails on it to another Exchange 2003 server?

Tags: exchange-2003

I have a junk Exchange 2003 environment.  It has two administrative groups.  I'm trying to consolidate all my administrative groups into one by migrating all the mailboxes from the "older" administrative group to the "less older" one (still Exchange 2003), before I start my upgrade to a newer environment.  I'm down to one stubborn mailbox.  When I try to move it, I get the error: `this mailbox exceeded the maximum number of corrupted items`

I've run `esutil /p` and `isinteg` on it.  It fixed some of my problems, but I still can't move the mailbox, because there are more errors. I don't care about the corrupt mail.  I just want to move the mailbox and have it ignore or purge the bad emails.  I've tried Exmerge, but it can't seems to communicate with the local ExchangeIS, which is weird, even though it is running.  I've restarted it multiple times.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I found the answer.  It was in the wizard for moving the mailbox to skipp errors.  I don't know how I missed it.